# Finding geared stepper motor speed

Tags: stepper-motor

I was trying to find the stepper motor speed and the datasheet shows that it has a gear ratio of 10(the data circled with red). I assume this means that the stepper motor has an attached gear head. My question is when I am calculating the speed should I include the gear ratio, meaning the speed will undergo a reduction of 10?
If include gear ratio factor, my motor speed is **6rpm**
[image: Gear Ratio is 10]

[image]

Or I should just refer to this graph to get my motor speed(rpm)?
**my pulse speed is 2000Hz.** If i straight away use the data in graph , I get speed around **60rpm.**
Sorry if this is an obvious question and I appreciate any inputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly have a 200 step/revolution motor with a 10:1 gear reduction...that is where the 0.18 degree per step comes from.

Your pulse speed is 2000 Hz....so, the actual motor is spinning 10 revolutions per second.  That is 600 RPM.  Then the gear head reduces the RPM by a factor of 10.  So, you have 60 RPM at the output shaft.

Comment: may i know why in the end you still need to divide by 10 for the rpm?Previously you already factored in the gear reduction in 200 step/rev calculation. So by using the 200 step/rev and 2000Hz, we get 10 rev/s which is 600 rpm(already include gear reduction).

Comment: No, 1.8 degrees/step or 200 steps/revolution is a very common standard for a stepper motor. So 200 steps/rev is almost certainly without gearbox.

Comment: There are no step motors made with a 0.18 degree step angle.  The actual step motor has a 1.8 degree step angle.  After 10:1 reduction, the output shaft moves at 0.18 degrees per step.